# How to force all data in to end on the same row?

Tags: r, row, na

I have a bunch of columns which all start on the same row but I would rather them all end on the same row. Here is a simplified example

```
A <- c(2,7,3,5,5,9,8,1,NA,NA)
B <- c(NA,5,2,1,6,4,6,7,NA,NA)
C <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3,6,7,1,5,6)

Start <- cbind(A,B,C)
```

Which gives:

```
       A  B  C
 [1,]  2 NA NA
 [2,]  7  5 NA
 [3,]  3  2 NA
 [4,]  5  1 NA
 [5,]  5  6  3
 [6,]  9  4  6
 [7,]  8  6  7
 [8,]  1  7  1
 [9,] NA NA  5
[10,] NA NA  6
```

But I want to manipulate this so it is output like this:

```
       A  B  C
 [1,] NA NA NA
 [2,] NA NA NA
 [3,]  2 NA NA
 [4,]  7  5 NA
 [5,]  3  2  3
 [6,]  5  1  6
 [7,]  5  6  7
 [8,]  9  4  1
 [9,]  8  6  5
[10,]  1  7  6
```

Couldn't really find a solution on this site. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
apply(Start, 2, function(x) rev(`length<-`(na.omit(rev(x)), nrow(Start))))

       A  B  C
 [1,] NA NA NA
 [2,] NA NA NA
 [3,]  2 NA NA
 [4,]  7  5 NA
 [5,]  3  2  3
 [6,]  5  1  6
 [7,]  5  6  7
 [8,]  9  4  1
 [9,]  8  6  5
[10,]  1  7  6
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `apply` + `is.na`

```
apply(Start,2,function(x) c(x[is.na(x)],x[!is.na(x)]))
```

or

```
apply(Start,2,function(x) do.call(c,rev(split(x,is.na(x)))))
```

such that

```
       A  B  C
 [1,] NA NA NA
 [2,] NA NA NA
 [3,]  2 NA NA
 [4,]  7  5 NA
 [5,]  3  2  3
 [6,]  5  1  6
 [7,]  5  6  7
 [8,]  9  4  1
 [9,]  8  6  5
[10,]  1  7  6
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a sort parameter for this:

```
A <- c(2,7,3,5,5,9,8,1,NA,NA)
B <- c(NA,5,2,1,6,4,6,7,NA,NA)
C <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,3,6,7,1,5,6)

Start <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C) ) # added "as.data.frame" here ..

do.call(cbind, lapply(Start, sort, na.last = FALSE))
```

Or:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(Start, function(x) {
  res <- sort(x, na.last = FALSE)
  res[!is.na(res)] <- x[!is.na(x)]
  res
}))

#     A  B  C
# [1,] NA NA NA
# [2,] NA NA NA
# [3,]  2 NA NA
# [4,]  7  5 NA
# [5,]  3  2  3
# [6,]  5  1  6
# [7,]  5  6  7
# [8,]  9  4  1
# [9,]  8  6  5
#[10,]  1  7  6
```

Comment: Thanks, all answers worked but this one was the most simple.

Comment: The use of `sort()` is a detour because this question doesn't need to sort values.

Comment: It creates the right number of NA's at the beginning of the vector. Of course it is necessary.

Comment: Yes my bad, it turns out for me that sort works as I am using data of total covid cases. But you're right, in general this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @r.user.05apr So you need the ability of `na.last`, not `sort()` itself. If this data is large, it's inefficient to sort values in a case that doesn't need to sort.